# Efficient way to download binary from server

Tags: rsync, bandwidth

I am using a remote machine to compile a project. When it finishes building, I use scp to copy the archive to a local machine.

This worked fine till I was on broadband. Now I am using a 3G connection as I am away from home and I have limited bandwidth. The archive is around 80 MiB in size and since I am not doing this smartly, I run out of bandwidth quite easily as I have to download the archive multiple times in a day.

Is there a better way to do this instead of having to download the file again and again? Should I be using something like `rsync`??

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
rsync -avP --inplace user@remote:/path/to/archive.dat CopyOfLocalArchive.dat
```

This tries only to transfer differences. If the archives are too different there won't be too much benefit. But maybe worth a try.

Comment: I'd also recommend using `-z` as an option for `rsync` to compress network traffic; on a slow link it will help, on a faster network the overhead may take more time than the compression saves. If you're using `gzip` to compress data first, be sure to use the `--rsyncable` option, and `-z` with rsync will still help with rsync's own data.